# Replicate update statement as Insert in Mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6

I want to replicate all update statement from Master as a Insert at Slave end.

Is it possible like in SQL Server? If so, how?

I want to do it because, if any record on Master is updating and if same record is not present at Slave end, then instead of Replication tends to fail, it should insert that record at Slave end.

All insert on Master will act as Insert only at Slave end.

Comment: Use replace into instead of insert and if the record is already present, it would first delete the old one and would insert the new one and if it is not present it would simply insert. This way even if the master have a record which slave doesn't, it would be update at master and insert on slave. Hope it helps

Comment: how can i implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

How about using [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) or [REPLACE INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html) on master itself?

Comment: i understand this,but this is for updation (Insert on..) when duplicate primary key present. I want to replicate update happening on master as Insert at slave.

Comment: I doubt (but will be interested to know) if that's possible in MySQL! Mostly not.